# How to change data source in Power Query of Excel 2016 by using Python scripts?

Tags: python, excel, automation, powerquery, datasource

I have an excel file (named **Test.xlsx**) that load data from an external source (a csv file) by Power Query. The query code is:

```
let  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\HUONGBT\file1.csv"),[Delimiter=",",Encoding=1252]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers", each ([A] <> "1"))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

I want to change the data source from "D:\HUONGBT\file1.csv" to "D:\HUONGBT\file2.csv" by using Python script for automation purpose. I don't want to open the **Test.xlsx**, go to Query Editor and modify the data source manually.
Please share with me if you have any solution! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you would be to create a fixed location text file that contains the filepath of the file you want powerquery to work on.  You can use python or whatever to set the contents of that pointer file

So for example, contents of pointer file D:\HUONGBT\location.txt would be

```
D:\HUONGBT\file2.csv
```

Then change your powerquery to first read the pointer file, then use the file it references within to continue

```
 let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(
        Csv.Document(File.Contents("D:\HUONGBT\location.txt")){0}[Column1]
),[Delimiter=",",Encoding=1252]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers", each ([A] <> "1"))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Alternate method is just to put your file in its own directory and use Folder.Files() to check the name of the file in there

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
....
```